Can you toggle between "Run" and "Run App"
I wrote a code in R that was executable with the typical green "Run" arrow. At the bottom of the code, I then added some shiny code involving ui, server, and shinyApp. Now I only see "Run App" instead of the "Run" option. Is there a way to toggle between the two run options? Or am I resigned to only running sections of code using highlight ctrl-enter whenever there is shiny code in the script?
See above for context.

Shiny apps are supposed to be run as a whole, because most shiny apps will use reactivity, i.e., perform calculations or events based on user input, which can not be reproduced directly in a not interactive context. What I do to test parts of my apps is just to keep a separate script in which I can run the expressions with specific parameters or placeholders to check if it runs, then I pass the working code into the app itself for live testing.

The moment you save your R script as "app.R", R Studio automatically assumes it is a Shiny app that needs to be compiled and run. If you want to explore elements of the Shiny package without creating or running an app, you can do something like shiny::actionButton( )
